# Substitute all version="n.n" occurrences except xml version with bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a bunch of files in the directory that has this pattern: `version="0"`. It can be any number inside. But I don't want to affect the `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` parts. This line can be not on the first line, so we can't just skip the first.
The main problem is that sed and awk's gsub don't work with lookbehind. I decided that it acceptable to do double work. replace all versions and then fix all xml versions. But sed with -r missunderstands the capturing groups.
What I have so far:

```
sed -r 's#(\<\?xml .*)version="[^"]*"(.*\?\>)#\1version="1.0"\2#g'  fixing xmls
```

Comment: You need to use an XML parser.

Comment: How can it be that the `<?xml `... can be "not on the first line"? That's probably not real xml then?

Answer (score 0):

To change all `version` attributes within an XML document, the following [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) command will suffice:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
  -u '//*[@version="0"]/@version' -v 1 \
  /your/directory/*.xml
```

Comment: sadly those could be not only xml files but files that just contains those lines. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I kind of made it:

```
find test -exec sed -i 's/version="[^"]*"/version="800"/g' {} \; -print | xargs -I FILE sed -i 's#\(<?xml \)version="[^"]*"\(.*\)#\1version="1.0"\2#g' FILE
```

where the 800 is desirable value. but still double work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the`<` and `>` if you don't use them for [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Try  this:

```
sed -r 's#(<\?xml .*)version="[^"]*"(.*\?>)#\1version="1.0"\2#g' file
```

That said you should avoid the *any character* `.*` pattern that is greedy. A safer command would be:

```
sed -r 's#(<\?xml[^>]*)version="[^"]*"([^>]*)\?>#\1version="1.0"\2?>#g' file
```